# Clarification of the diagram in Theorem 2.20 (Lucchini) in Isaacs's Finite Group Theory

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

I was revisiting group theory in detail and reading Isaacs's Finite Group Theory book in my own time. I need a little clarification on the diagram in the proof of Theorem 2.20 on page 63 of the book. This is in continuation of my [previous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3824121/clarification-of-a-part-of-theorem-2-20-in-isaacss-finite-group-theory/3824139#3824139) question. My apologies for another question.

Here is the set-up:

> - $G$ is a non-trivial finite group and let $\mathbb F(G)$ be the [Fitting subgroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitting_subgroup) of $G$.
> - $A$ is a cyclic proper subgroup (with trivial [core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_(group_theory))) of $G$ such that $|A|\ge |G:A|$ and $A\cap \mathbb F(G)>1$.
> - $\mathbb F(G)>1$ and we can choose a minimal normal subgroup $E$ of $G$ with $E \subseteq Z(\mathbb F(G))$.
> - $E$ is an elementary abelian $p$-group for some prime $p$.
> - Further $A\cap \mathbb F(G)\trianglelefteq AE$ and $AE\subset G$ but $AE\ne G$.

The next part of the proof relies on this diagram given on page 63:
[image]

It is not explicitly mentioned in the book what is $M$. Later it is used to define $\bar M=\text{core}_{G/E}(\bar A)$ with $E\subseteq M$, $M\trianglelefteq G$ and $AM=AE$.

My question is:

> What actually the subgroup $M$ is? In particular what is $\bar A$?

I was thinking maybe Theorem 2.18 (Zenkov) might be used which says that if $K$ is a finite group and $X$, $Y$ are abelian subgroups of $K$ then a minimal member $M$ of the set $\{ X\cap Y^g \mid g \in K\}$ satisfies $M\subseteq \mathbb F(K)$; here $M$ is a minimal member of this set in the sense that no member of the set is properly contained in $M$. But I am not sure if this minimal $M$ is somehow related to my original question.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

With $\overline{G} = G/E$, the notation used in the book for a subgroup $H \leq G$ is that $\overline{H}$ is the image of $H$ in $G/E$. See page 22 and 23 there.

So to answer your question: $M$ is the unique subgroup $E \leq M \leq G$ such that $M/E = \overline{M}$.